# Only use last X values in a plot in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to automatically measure the temperature and humidity in my room and append that data to a Google sheet every few minutes. I use several methods to display the current data (gauges look nice for that) but I haven't found a way to conveniently tell my line chart to only use, for example, the last three days of values.

Is there a nice way of doing this?

[Link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q2MtosIXoDhb3q58p_rLpsWysrEzQ7k8vRaeBAqb6FM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: pls, share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @user0 I added a link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY('Zimmer WG Fuwa'!A:C; "limit 90 offset "&(COUNTA('Zimmer WG Fuwa'!A:A)-90))
```

[image: 0]

---

- for last 3 days it would be:

```
=QUERY('Zimmer WG Fuwa'!A:C; 
 "where A <= date '"&TEXT(MAX('Zimmer WG Fuwa'!A:A);   "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
    and A >= date '"&TEXT(MAX('Zimmer WG Fuwa'!A:A)-3; "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"; 1)
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**. Please describe how this post answers the question.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using the query function before but it didn't work for me for some reason...